# Why is the Storm Hook error-method removed?

Tags: java, error-handling, hook, apache-storm

I am currently considering how to create some error-handling framework, for use in internal Storm applications. I saw that up until Storm v. 0.7.5 the BaseTaskHook-class had an `error`-method, taking a `Throwable` as parameter, which seemed perfect for what I wanted to do. But since v. 0.8.0 it has been removed. Can anyone tell me why that is? And, if it is because it's just bad practice to use; what would be considered good practice?